# angular: calling/triigering directive method from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

in my app I defined a directive which implement a simple slider with a next/prev/goto methods. 
The slider then is within an html snipet managed by another controller. 
The problem is that the last slide contains a form, so if the submit is ok than I would like to go to the next slide.

In old javascript I would have passed a callback to the submit method in order to apply that callback. 
I made the same thing. Is this the best / angular style way to do it?

Javascript (I omitted some detail):

```
.directive("sfCarousel", function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            var slides = $scope.slides = [];
            var currentIndex = $scope.currentIndex = -1;

            $scope.next = function() {
                //mynextfunction...
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("sf-carousel");
        }
    }
})
.directive("sfCarouselItem", function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: '^sfCarousel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, sfCarouselController) {
            console.log("sf-carousel-item");
            sfCarouselController.addSlide(scope);
        }
    }
})
.controller("mycontroller", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function (callback) {
        //if submit is ok then 
        callback.apply(null, []);
    }
}])
```

HTML:

```
<div sf-carousel >  
    <div sf-carousel-item  ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <div>my first slide</div>
        <div sf-label="get-started.submit" ng-click="next()" ></div>
    </div> 
    <div sf-carousel-item ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <form>
            <!--here my form-->
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submit(next)">submit and go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div sf-carousel-item ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <div>my last slide</div>
        <!--other things-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you try something like `submit()?next():null`? it would be great if you can provide jsfiddle or plunker

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that you what to run on the parent controller.

```
// directive sfCarousel

return {
transclude: true,
template: '<div class="sf-carousel" ng-transclude></div>',
// ...
};
// directive sfCarouselItem
return {
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    func: '&',
    // ...
  },
  template: '<div class="sf-carousel-item" ng-transclude></div>',
}


// controller html

<div sf-carousel >  
    <div sf-carousel-item  ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <div>my first slide</div>
        <div sf-label="get-started.submit" ng-click="next()" ></div>
    </div> 
    <div sf-carousel-item func="next()" ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <form>
            <!--here my form-->
            <button type="submit"  ng-click="func({})">submit and go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div sf-carousel-item ng-class="{'active':active}" >
        <div>my last slide</div>
        <!--other things-->
    </div>
</div>
```